# How to do batch processing on kafka connect generated datasets?

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect

Suppose we have batch jobs producing records into kafka and we have a kafka connect cluster consuming records and moving them to HDFS. We want the ability to run batch jobs later on the same data but we want to ensure that batch jobs see the whole records generated by producers. What is a good design for this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What issues are you running into?

Answer (score 0):

You can run any MapReduce, Spark, Hive, etc query on the data, and you will get all records that have been thus far been written to HDFS. It will not see data that has not been consumed by the Sink from the producers, but this has nothing to do with Connect or HDFS, that is a pure Kafka limitation.

Worth pointing out that [Apache Pinot](https://pinot.apache.org/) is a better place to combine Kafka streaming data and have batch query support.

Comment: But I want to be able to make sure that batch jobs know that a batch is incomplete (maybe kafka connect is not working properly or maybe producers are not producing enough messages to kafka). I don't want to let incomplete metrics being generated on top of datasets.

Comment: That's not possible out of the box. Kafka Consumers and any application processing the data that is consumed is completely decoupled from the Producer. You'll need to export Kafka consumer lag to an external system (like Burrow), then your batch jobs can query that. Or you can otherwise use Kafka ConsumerInterceptors to report "outward" somewhere that a batch is "ready" (however, this will fail to account for late data that is produced into your topics)